# Swiping and Panning Gestures on the same HTML element on a iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, mobile

I used a slightly modified version of Ryan Scherf's jQuery swipe plugin on a web page to make LI elements in a UL swipable.  When I view this page in the iPhone, I noticed that while swiping is working inside the LI element, I can no longer pan to move up or down the page.  It seems that by adding event listeners to the LI, I have disabled the default listeners.  This is my first time trying to implement touch gesture on the iPhone, so I'm not sure how to support panning.

The Apple documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) talks about how panning generates an onscroll event, but I'm not sure if I can use that.

I have the code here for anybody to examine.
http://jsfiddle.net/tangst/drnSp/

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, having event.preventDefault() on the touchMove will negate the default panning behavior.  I updated the jsfiddle.